# Python pandas applymap error handling for unexpected value

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Error handling for .applymap()

I was thinking about how to handle errors.

I was reviewing the pandas applymap() docs and found ignore_na but that’s not what I’m looking for.

This is the DataFrame

`df`

| SNP_1 | SNP_2 | SNP_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T:G | T:G | ACC:ACC |
| T:G | T:G | ACC:ACC |
| T:G | T:G | ACC:ACC |

```
dict_map = {'T:G': 'K'}
df = df.applymap(lambda x: dict_map[x])
```

```
KeyError: 'ACC:ACC'
```

I get an error, obviously. Actually, I didn't expect to find that in the dataframe. Now I want to get rid of the whole column.

The expected output would be a dictionary mapped dataframe without the `df['SNP_3']` column. Is there a way to identify a column to remove while applying a dictionary map?

`df`

| SNP_1 | SNP_2 |
| --- | --- |
| K | K |
| K | K |
| K | K |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. First, fill the non mappable column with `NaN` then drop them:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: dict_map[x] if x in dict_map else pd.NA)
df = df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Output:

```
  SNP_1 SNP_2
0     K     K
1     K     K
2     K     K
```

Answer (score 2):

i don't know. it can help solved your problem.

```
dict_map = { 'T:G': 'K'}
df = df.applymap(lambda x: dict_map[x] if x in dict_map else "")
```

| SNP_1 | SNP_2 | SNP_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K | k |  |
| K | k |  |
| K | k |  |